# Mysql trigger after update check how many columns were changed

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table that has 47 columns and i need if/else that if there is only one column was changed and the others stayed same else the others were changed but the one stayed same.

I can't check all column in if because new column may be added and also it does not seem healthy.

I could not find any suggestions on internet except "check all new and old value".

Is there no way to check when one column changes and other stays same?

Comment: Is this a pure mysql question or are you working with java or something like that?

Comment: No, unfortunately (for you) there is no other way than checking all columns, since you can't use dynamic sql in triggers. And btw, in databases, knowing the exact columns is the healthy thing. Adding columns on the other hand is not, so you have to do some work like adding it to the trigger if you do add columns.

Comment: @aleksv there is pure mysql i am working on.

Comment: @Solarflare thank you. It is kind of startup project so we may add sometime new column to table. As i understand i have to check those 46 columns and one column.